# WSO2 API Manager - Rhino version, repository and license

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

In API Manager distribution we see "org.mozilla.javascript" (/repository/components/plugins/js_1.7.0.R4wso2v1.jar)

We believe this is actually Mozilla Rhino project.

We see also rhino.wso2 in POM.xml

I see in GitHub: github.com/mozilla/rhino, but I assume WSO2 forked the code base and maintains a different repository.

What is the actual repository for Rhino version that is being consumed in WSO2 API manager?

We see:   http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/  and also   http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/rhino/wso2/js/1.7.0.R4.wso2v1/
What is the actual macen repro in use?

What is actual license of the actual Rhino version?

1. I understand from the license file it is **MPL10**
2. In maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/
   we see the license **MPL 2.0**
3. developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/License specifies it differently

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically query the underlying Rhino implementation to return the Rhino version, see here: http://nimbleapi.com/2016/05/javascript-getting-the-rhino-version/. Not sure if this will assist you to determine the repository or licence. Good luck!

Here is an excerpt:

```
// importPackage to get access to the required libraries,
//  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java

importPackage(Packages.org.mozilla.javascript);

var myContext = Context
var currentContext = myContext.getCurrentContext()
var rhinoVersion = currentContext.getImplementationVersion()
// Set the messagePayload to the rhino version in JSON format
var myPayload = { "rhinoVersion": rhinoVersion }
mc.setPayloadJSON(myPayload)
```